# Buildapp and debugger

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am writing a program with SBCL and building it with Buildapp.
Currently when error occurs it starts debugger. I want it to die in the same manner as other simple (C) programs do. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to put `(sb-ext:disable-debugger)` early in your startup function. When an error occurs and there is no handler, SBCL will print an error and a backtrace and exit.

Another option is to write a function that does what you want on error and set it as your debugger hook; see [command-line-debugger](https://github.com/xach/buildapp/blob/master/buildapp.lisp#L164) in buildapp itself for an example.